# threejs get center of object

Tags: 3d, three.js

I have trying to retrieve and plot the centerpoint of some objects but I keep getting the same value for all my objects which is x=0, y=0 and z=0. So my centerpoint is always the centerpoint of the scene. I'm currently reading up on 3D computer matrixes so I'm a bit novice in this area. Do I need to update the scene somehow or update some matrix after every added object or something?

```
function initBoxes(){
    var box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    box.position.set(0, 2, 2);
    getCenterPoint(box);

    var box2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    box2.position.set(0, 6, 6);
    getCenterPoint(box2);
}

function getCenterPoint(mesh) {
    var middle = new THREE.Vector3();
    var geometry = mesh.geometry;

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    middle.x = (geometry.boundingBox.max.x + geometry.boundingBox.min.x) / 2;
    middle.y = (geometry.boundingBox.max.y + geometry.boundingBox.min.y) / 2;
    middle.z = (geometry.boundingBox.max.z + geometry.boundingBox.min.z) / 2;

    return middle;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The object `boundingBox` is in local space. If you want the center in world space you have to translate your `middle` vertex to world space. You can do that easily with [the `THREE.Object3D` `localToWorld`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D.localToWorld) method like this:

```
function getCenterPoint(mesh) {
    var middle = new THREE.Vector3();
    var geometry = mesh.geometry;

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    middle.x = (geometry.boundingBox.max.x + geometry.boundingBox.min.x) / 2;
    middle.y = (geometry.boundingBox.max.y + geometry.boundingBox.min.y) / 2;
    middle.z = (geometry.boundingBox.max.z + geometry.boundingBox.min.z) / 2;

    mesh.localToWorld( middle );
    return middle;
}
```

---

### Update:

In the newer three.js versions there is [a convenience method `getCenter`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3.getCenter) inside the `THREE.Box3` class. Since the bounding box is in local coordinate space you will need to project the result to worldspace to get the center in world coordinates, but this is easy with the `localToWorld` method from the parent object.

```
function getCenterPoint(mesh) {
    var geometry = mesh.geometry;
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    var center = new THREE.Vector3();
    geometry.boundingBox.getCenter( center );
    mesh.localToWorld( center );
    return center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It kind of works now but.... Could you maybe point me into the right direction on where to read up on coordinates-systems? I find it very confusing. There is Local, global and world-coordinates?

Comment: Global and world space is the same thing. World space is the global coordinate system (relative to the origin of your scene). Local space is the local coordinate system relative to the origin of the object itself.

Comment: getCenter now recevies a Vector. To remove the warning use: `const center = new THREE.Vector3(); geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(center)`

Answer (score 3):

try the code below:

```
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(myObject3D)
let sphere = box.getBoundingSphere()
let centerPoint = sphere.center
```

THREE.Box3().setFromObject(Object3D) will traverse the Object3D's geometries, and return their holistic bounding Box.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This answer has some problems. My friend pointed me a similar solution: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L215

Comment: The above link points to the `master` branch. This following link points to the current commit as of the time of the above comment: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/7ad14efd8369e4f57a242647c10a9703407c09e2/src/viewer.js#L215

Answer (score 0):

Update of first Method:

```
getCenterPoint(mesh) {
        let middle = new THREE.Vector3();
        let geometry = mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh || mesh.isMesh ? mesh.geometry : mesh;

        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.boundingBox.getSize(middle);

        middle.x = middle.x / 2;
        middle.y = middle.y / 2;
        middle.z = middle.z / 2;

        mesh.localToWorld(middle);
        return middle;
    }
```